# Gateway laptop module bay light repeating 12 flashes - what error is that?

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade

I have a Gateway M465-E laptop currently running fine with a T2300E Core Duo installed.  I wanted to upgrade it to a Core 2 Duo.  My brother has the same model laptop and that took a Core 2 Duo (T7200) just fine.

Picked up a T7200 on ebay and installed it.

Normally when booting all the indicator lights flash once and the fan spins up before the machine actually starts to POST.  With the T7200 installed all the lights flash and the fan spins up, but the module bay activity light flashes 12 times repeatedly.

I'm assuming this is an error code, but can find no information about it.  There are no beep codes.

I've removed the ram, HD, Bay module and no change.  Switched back to the T2300E and everything works fine.

Anyone know what that error code is?

The motherboard was actually manufactured by Foxconn if that helps.

**Update 1**
Returned the CPU as defective.  I tested it in 3 M465-E's and all of them did exactly the same thing.  I still have no idea what the error code is.  I'd still like to know for future reference.

Perhaps I should try removing the CPU from one of them and see what happens.

Comment: Can't say this is the reason - but two same-model-number computers from most manufacturers don't necessarily contain the same components. The component suppliers and firmware versions will change over time. Are bios/firmware updates for both machines at the same revision?

Comment: Yup, what barryj says is backed up by a thread on tomshardware concerning your exact issue;  http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/285911-28-gateway-m465-processor-upgrade

Comment: Updated the bios during testing, didn't change anything.

Comment: That thread on tomshardware was started by me when I was upgrading my brothers laptop.  During testing the BIOS version did NOT effect whether the CPU worked or not.  Also, during those tests I never ran into the flashing bay light.  The light is new and I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a specific error code consisting of 12 flashes rather than an error code consisting of "flash on and off for approximately 10 seconds", then it will be documented in the motherboard reference (manual) for that laptop. If you did not get a proper manual with the laptop, try browsing through the manufacturer's web site. Without documentation, one can only guess, and you have probably already guessed that it means "incompatible CPU frequency" or some such.